# Como usar GroupBy de acordo com parâmetro?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Tenho minha *Model* de conta como abaixo:

```
public class Conta
{
    public int Id {get;set;}

    public int ClienteId {get;set;}
    public Cliente Cliente {get;set;}

    public int ContaBancariaId {get;set;}
    public ContaBancaria ContaBancaria {get;set;}

    public int PlanoId {get;set;}
    public Plano Plano {get;set;}

    public string Descricao {get;set;}
    public DateTime Data {get;set;}
    public decimal Valor {get;set;}
}
```

Para meu filtro e resultado eu tenho as seguintes models:

```
public class ContaBusca
{
    public AgruparPor AgruparPor {get;set;}

}
public enum AgruparPor 
{
   Cliente,
   ContaBancaria,
   Plano
}
```

E meu retorno é o seguinte:

```
public class ContaResultadoBusca
{
    public string Nome {get;set;} //Pode ser o nome do Cliente, Conta Bancaria ou Plano
    public List<ContaResultadoBuscaItem> Contas {get;set;}
}

public class ContaResultadoBuscaItem 
{
    public string Descricao {get;set;}
    public DateTime Data {get;set;}
    public decimal Valor {get;set;}
}
```

E no meu serviço eu recebo o parametro e retorno da seguinte forma

```
   public class ContaServico
    {
        public ContaResultadoBusca AgruparPor(AgruparPor agrupador)
        {
            if (agrupador == AgruparPor.Cliente)
            {
                return dbo.Contas.GroupBy(conta => conta.Cliente).Select(conta => new ContaResultadoBusca { Nome = conta.Nome })..
            }
            if(agrupador == AgruparPor.ContaBancaria)
            {
                return dbo.Contas.GroupBy(conta => conta.ContaBancaria).Select(conta => new ContaResultadoBusca { Nome = conta.Nome })..
            }


    }
    }
```

Como eu posso agrupar de acordo com o parametro passado sem ter que fazer tantos `if`?
No exemplo tem apenas 2, mas poderia ser mais...

Comment: Neste caso que você exemplificou, desconheço outra forma a não ser a utilização de um switch ao invés do if. O que se pode fazer também é ter um método para fabricar a Expression do agrupamento, mais de toda forma vai ter uma estrutura de controle para identificar o agrupamento

Comment: @JulioBorges eu poderia usar operação ternária dentro do groupBy...Mas se tiver muitos agrupadores fica muito ruim a manutenção e leitura do código...

Comment: Com certeza ficaria muito ruim, o melhor mesmo será substituir o if por um switch.

Comment: O legal do Switch é que se você deixar de implementar uma opção do enum o compilador te avisa e fica mais fácil para evitar erros por falta de implementação

Comment: É, mas ainda tenho a duplicação do meu Select...Isso que não estou gostando...Tentei com Func também

Comment: a unica forma de vc fazer isso é se vc usar o polimorfismo tendo sua entidade Conta como abstrata e o restante herdando dela. na Conta vc teria os dados como id e nome.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza, boa opção também

Comment: Se a coluna coincide com a string do enum, você pode fazer com uma Linq Query

Comment: @LeandroAngelo particularmente eu ñao gosto da syntax de linq query rsrsrs Mas responda aí...Se for a única opção...

Answer (score 3):

O seu model deve refletir a seguinte hierarquia:

[image: Hierarquia de models]

Uma vez feito isso, alterar o contexto do BD da seguinte forma:

```
public virtual DbSet<Conta> Contas { get; set; }
```

No ponto onde há consulta ao contexto do BD, fazer da seguinte forma:

```
public ContaResultadoBusca AgruparPor(Type type)
{
    IEnumerable<Conta> query;

    query = dbo.Contas
        .Where(where => where.GetType() == type);
    ...
    return new ContaResultadoBusca(nome, MapearResultado(query));
}

....
```

No ponto onde há consumo de models, fazer:

```
public IActionResult ConsumirServico(ContaBusca contaBusca)
{
    ContaResultadoBusca model = null;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        AgruparPor agruparPor = contaBusca.AgruparPor;

        Type type = Type.GetType($"MeuNamespace.Models.{agruparPor}");

        model = Servico.AgruparPor(type);
        ...
     }

     ...
     return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma pouco dinâmica, porém funcional, é adicionar propriedades estáticas do tipo `Expression<Func<Conta, TKey>>`(este é o tipo de dado que a função `GroupBy` do `IEnumerable` usa para interpretar e gerar o SQL) e usá-las pra passar como parâmetro no método `Agrupar` do serviço:

A classe conta:

```
public class Conta
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }

    public int ContaBancariaId { get; set; }
    public ContaBancaria ContaBancaria { get; set; }

    public int PlanoId { get; set; }
    public Plano Plano { get; set; }

    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }

    public static Expression<Func<Conta, Cliente>> AgrupamentoPorCliente
        => c => c.Cliente;

    public static Expression<Func<Conta, ContaBancaria>> AgrupamentoPorContaBancaria
        => c => c.ContaBancaria;

    public static Expression<Func<Conta, Plano>> AgrupamentoPorPlano
        => c => c.Plano;
}
```

O método de agrupamento do `ContaServico`:

```
public ContaResultadoBusca Agrupar<TType, TKey>(Expression<Func<TType, TKey>> exp)
    where TType : Conta
    where TKey : class
{
    return dbo.Contas.GroupBy(exp).Select(conta => new ContaResultadoBusca { Nome = conta.Nome });
}
```